# Telegram : automatic opening of secondary chats

Tags: bots, chat, telegram, telegram-bot

We have a telegram channel in which we publish links of organized events. We would like to offer the possibility for our users to have a separate chat for each event in order to avoid confusion on the main chat. The chat should open automatically by clicking on the message containing the link.
it is a feature that I have seen made on the others channels I frequent but I don't know how to use it. can you help me?